# Jenkins error cs0246 al compilar

Tags: jenkins

estoy configurando Jenkins, y me sale el siguiente error cuando compilo

```
13:17:31   FISLib\Factories\AutoFaketoryBC.cs(1,7): error CS0246:
El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'ResourceTrackingModel' no se encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?) 
[C:\Jenkins\jobs\ERESPONSE_CORE\workspace\ERESPONSEClient_XXXXXXX\ERESPONSEClient_XXXXXXXXXX.csproj]
```

Me salen 11 errores todos de este tipo.
El problema esta en que no encuentra los archivos (creo), pero no se como indicarle la ruta. Intenté añadir:

```
using ResourceTrackingModel;
```

en el archivo AutoFaketoryBc.cs pero nada.

¿Debería poner la ruta absoluta del archivo ResourceTrackingModel?

(( using C:\Jenkins\jobs.......\ResourceTrackingModel  ))

¿ Tengo que cambiar el archivo .csproj ?

¿ Por que leches compila fuera de Jenkins y dentro de Jenkins no?

Muchas gracias de antemano si alguien sabe algo

Answer (score 0):

En jenkins podes configurar un workspace distinto al que te genera automáticamente, y el mismo debería ser con la misma estructura que lo tienes en tu pc, de esta forma no deberías tener problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]